# JQuery Ajax Post - JSON works with GET but NOT with POST

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to send json string to the server using jquery ajax, as below.  It decodes correctly when GET is used, but does not work when POST is used.  Any suggestions?

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
        url: "../pssops21/php/insertTempTransData.php",
        data: 'data=' + strSelectedItems,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: handleresponse                 
    });
```

Server side php:

```
$json = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']), true);
```

After the comments, I realize it is not an ajax post issue, but a decoding issue.

Thank you.

Comment: what does your server side php code look like?

Comment: check if print_r($_POST) yields any results

Comment: It's not a method call mis match.

Comment: Yes, it yields results: [[{\"TransactionID\":\"00423\",\"OrderID\":\"000937\",\"Transactio etc

Answer (score 2):

i think on the server side you need to have $_POST['strSelectedItems'] instead of $_POST['data'] .. or do a print_r($_POST) to get a clearer picture , i think the js is ok, but i am not a jquery expert.

Comment: do print_r($_POST) to see what's being sent as proposed above

Comment: Sorry, that was a posting mistake.  I changed the variable names later.

Comment: @Natkeeran ... if you use firefox , i would suggest you look in the firebug console and see what sort of parameters are being sent. and if i understand correctly u have already tried print_r($_POST) on the receiving end?

Comment: Yes, firebug posts this:
data [[{"TransactionID":"00425", "EndDate":"2009-12-31"}]]
I realize the issue in the decoding side, for some reason json_decode works with GET, and not with POST as expected.

Comment: can u please post the exact and complete output of print_r($_POST)